# Access parent context from ember component block

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to work out how blocks work with ember components. With the following I'd expect project.name to be rendered for each loop.

```
// components/block-test.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({});

// index.hbs
{{#each project in projects}}
    {{#block-test}}
        {{project.name}}
    {{/block-test}}
{{/each}}
```

But when I use this pattern project.name is not rendered. Is this the expected behaviour and if so how could I change it to get the above code to work?

Answer (score 4):

component's are intentionally isolated, pass in anything you want to use (you don't need yield if you are passing it in)

```
{{#block-test project=project}}
    --{{project.name}}--
{{/block-test}}
```

No Component template

```
 --apple--
 --dog--
 --piano--
```

With yield

Component template

```
--{{yield}}--
```

Using Component

```
{{#block-test}}
    {{project.name}}
{{/block-test}}


 --apple--
 --dog--
 --piano--
```

Comment: Hello again! This is different to how e.g. rails and angular do it, is this because it's more in line with the future web components spec?

Comment: P.S. having played around a bit more you don't seem to need the {{yield}} at all. I've removed it from the component I'm working on and it still works.

Comment: That's exactly why, hmm, they must have changed that in the last 6 months, good to know, thx!

Comment: I remember, they recently made the change where a template wasn't required for components.

Comment: Are you sure about context? The [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component) still says **It's important to note that the template scope inside the component block is the same as outside. If a property is available in the template outside the component, it is also available inside the component block.**. I do what @opsb does in my app, but my app is still on 1.0.0-309

Comment: That's only if you include yield

Comment: Without a yield(and template) the block portion is just the template, and not in scope of the outer world

Comment: With a yield you're essentially saying render the outside scope here

Comment: The block portion no longer has access to the component scoped variables

Comment: @kingpin2k ok, that makes a lot of sense now, thanks!